# How toGet users input from JTextFIeld to JTable,does't work in my code

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtable, jtextfield

I have project to get from users input like name,surname,to save to Jtable,i have table and jtextfiled but when user get input they don t save to table.
The table is show,but not users input.
 here is my code:

```
enter code here public class Projektni extends JFrame {
public final JTextField ime = new JTextField(10);
public final JTextField prezime = new JTextField(10);
public final JTextField index = new JTextField(10);
public DefaultListModel podaci = new DefaultListModel();
public JList lista = new JList(podaci);
String kolone[] = {"ID","Name","Age"};
   //prazan konstruktor gde implementiramo i definisemo dugmice,polja za upisivanje podataka i                           osluskivace
  public Projektni()
    {

     DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(); 
      JTable table = new JTable(model); 
       String nextRowId = Integer.toString(model.getRowCount());
       model.addColumn("Ime"); 
       model.addColumn("Prezime"); 
       model.addColumn("Indeks");
        model.addRow((new Object[] { 
          nextRowId,
          ime.getText(),
          prezime.getText(),
          index.getText()}


           ));

      repaint();

    JPanel pane2=new JPanel (new GridLayout(6, 7));   
      pane2.add(table);
     pane2.setVisible(true);


    ime.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,80));
    prezime.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,80));
    index.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,40));
    JPanel panel=new JPanel (new GridLayout(6, 7));
    panel.add(new JLabel("Ime studenta:"));
    panel.add(ime);
        panel.add(new JLabel("Prezime studenta:"));
        panel.add(prezime);
        panel.add(new JLabel("Broj indeksa studenta:"));
     panel.add(index);
         panel.setBackground(Color.cyan);

      String[] seminari = {"Microsoft","MAC","Java"};
      final JComboBox cek = new JComboBox(seminari);
        panel.add(cek);

    JButton upisibtn=new JButton("Upisi");
      upisibtn.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(30,30));
       JTabbedPane tab = new JTabbedPane();
   getContentPane().add(tab);
   tab.add("Tab1",panel);
   tab.add("Tab2",pane2);

      upisibtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
  {

@Override

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
     {
    try{
        String p=nazivZaUnosNaziva()+" "+nazivZaUnosPrezimena()+" "+nemaIndeX()+"     "+cek.getSelectedItem()+"\n";
     String s=ime.getText()+" "+prezime.getText()+" "+index.getText()+"  "+cek.getSelectedItem()+"\n";

    Upisi.upisi(s);
    }
    catch(NemaNaziv|NemaIndeks|NemaPrezime ex){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);

    }





       }
      }
             );

   //Dugme prikazi ,koji prikazuje upisane podatke preko klase citaj.
      JButton citajbtn=new JButton("Prikazi");
        citajbtn.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(30,30));
       citajbtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
       {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
        for(String s:Citaj.citaj())
     podaci.addElement(s);

    }
     });

        //Dodavanje komponenata na panel.
        panel.add(upisibtn);
      panel.add(citajbtn);

     panel.add(lista);
      }

       //Vraca string naziva studenta,ukoliko nije upisan vraca izuzetak
       public String nazivZaUnosNaziva() throws NemaNaziv {
        String naziv = ime.getText();
        if (naziv.equals("")) {
        throw new NemaNaziv("Niste uneli naziv studenta. ");
    }
    return naziv;
        }
        //Vraca string prezime studenta,ukoliko nije upisan vraca izuzetak
      public String nazivZaUnosPrezimena() throws NemaPrezime {
    String prez = prezime.getText();
    if (prez.equals("")) {
        throw new NemaPrezime("Niste uneli prezime studenta. ");
    }
    return prez;
}
//Vraca string index studenta,ukoliko nije upisan vraca izuzetak
 public String nemaIndeX() throws NemaIndeks {
    String indeks = index.getText();
    if (indeks.equals("")) {
        throw new NemaIndeks("Niste unelii ndeks studenta. ");
    }
    return indeks;
}






//pokretacki metod
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    Projektni tp = new Projektni();
    tp.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    tp.setVisible(true);
    tp.setSize(600, 800);

}


}
```

Comment: Your code has lots of unresolved references to code not shown, meaning that it will not compile nor run for us, and so we cannot reproduce your problem with your code. If camickr's answer (1+ to it) does not solve your problem, then consider taking a little time to create and post a [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 3):

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(); 
      JTable table = new JTable(model); 
       String nextRowId = Integer.toString(model.getRowCount());
       model.addColumn("Ime"); 
       model.addColumn("Prezime"); 
       model.addColumn("Indeks");
        model.addRow((new Object[] { 
          nextRowId,
          ime.getText(),
          prezime.getText(),
          index.getText()}
```

When the above code is executed the text fields don't contain any text.

If you want the user to enter text and then add the text to the table then you need to add a JButton to you GUI. Then when the user clicks the button you can get the text from the text fields and add a new row to the TableModel.

Comment: Thanks,can you give me some simple example for that?

Comment: @BlueMaster: surely you can look up a JButton tutorial and at least make an attempt at creating a JButton add an ActionListener to it, and then updating your JTable, right?

Comment: I know how to pick up from jtextfield but with one jtetfield and one jbutton ,but i dont know how with one button pick up 3 users input from 3 jtextfield.

Comment: @BlueMaster: The secret to learning to program (and most anything in life) is to be able to learn a general lesson and then apply it to specific circumstances. If you know how to get text from *one* JTextField, I can't imagine that you don't know how to get text from three. This is a bit hard for me to believe since it's exactly the same as with one, except you have three lines in your code instead of one.

Comment: `This is a bit hard for me to believe since it's exactly the same as with one, except you have three lines in your code instead of one.` I totally agree.

Comment: i do that like this imeB.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            
            
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
             String pokupiIme=ime.getText();
             String pokupiPrezime=prezime.getText();
             String pokupiIndex=index.getText();
             
                
            }
        }
        );

Comment: @BlueMaster: fine, you're getting the three Strings, now you have to do something with them inside of your actionPerformed method. Keep forging ahead.